# How to make a small image move from one side of the screen to the other with js or jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have a small animated plane which has the sign that says " Welcome to the site " and I want it to move in a loop from left screen to the right. Just come out, then disappear. Now, I know this can been done with JS, but I have no idea. Is it very hard to move one image in JS?

Comment: This is very embarrassing, but I don't know how. I am new to this site.

Answer (score 6):

With the help of [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can animate almost anything

> **[.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete)**
>
> - **properties**
>     Type:  [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)
>     An object of CSS properties and values that the animation will move toward.
> - **duration**  (default:  `400`)
>     Type:  [Number](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Number)  or  [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)
>     A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
> - **easing**  (default:  `swing`)
>     Type:  [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)
>     A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
> - **complete**
>     Type:  [Function](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function)()
>     A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

For the *loop* we wrap the actual animation part into a named function and pass this as the `complete` callback. With that the animation will restart once it has finished.

```js
$(function() {
    var img = $("#plane"),
        width = img.get(0).width,
        screenWidth = $(window).width(),
        duration = 5000;

    function animatePlane() {
        img.css("left", -width).animate({
            "left": screenWidth
        }, duration, animatePlane);
    }

    animatePlane();
});
```

```css
body { overflow: hidden }
#plane { position: absolute; left: -1000px; width: 50% /* <- not relevant for the animation */ }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plane" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/13/10/18/aircraft-3674305_640.png" />
<!-- source: https://pixabay.com/de/flugzeuge-propeller-aircraft-alt-3674305/ -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can animate anything.  My code will animate a div (with an image, or any content you like) across the screen:

HTML:

```
<div id="animate">Sample</div>
```

CSS:

```
#animate {
    position: relative;
    border; 1px solid green;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = "+=" + $(document).width();
    $("#animate").animate({
    left: width
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2RPq/).

You could put anything you wanted in the div.  The only important part of the CSS is the "position: relative;" attribute.  You could change "#animate" from an id to a class and cause several objects to animate across the screen.  jQuery is very versatile.

If you wanted the animation to roll back from the right to the left again, change the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = $(document).width();

    function goRight() {
        $("#animate").animate({
        left: width
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
      });
    }
    function goLeft() {
        $("#animate").animate({
        left: 0
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goRight, 50);
      });
    }

    setTimeout(goRight, 50);
});
```

Working jsFiddle for that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2RPq/1/)

To make the image roll right and disappear forever, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = "+=" + $(document).width();
    $("#animate").animate({
    left: width
  }, 5000, function() {
    $("#animate").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Working jsFiddle for that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2RPq/2/)

Answer (score -1):

## Use marquee:

```
<marquee 
`scrollamount="10"`
 direction="left"
 behavior="scroll">
 Welcome to the site 
 <img src="images/plane.jpg" />
 </marquee>
```