# Move image from one side of screen to the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to move an image from one side of the screen to the other. I found this post that explains it - [How to make a small image move from one side of the screen to the other with js or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712592/how-to-make-a-small-image-move-from-one-side-of-the-screen-to-the-other-with-js). However I cannot get it to work. My image sits on the screen and then disappears. It does not go across the screen. I am following the example so I don't know why it does not act the same.

```
<div> 
    <img id="animate" src="myImage.png" />
</div>
@section scripts
{
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = "+=" + $(document).width();
    $("#animate").animate({
        left: width
    }, 5000, function() {
        $("#animate").css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: Did you set the image's `position` css property? eg `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`. The `left` and `top` css properties aren't used with the default `position`

Comment: that is what I was missing - I put in a css property of `position: relative;` -- thank-you Patrick